# Enlarge image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I really don't know how can I make the same effect with images like on this page. Like you will see, there is article with small image but when user click on the image it enlarges on the full width. Does anyone has idea how to make replica of this?

Thanks in advance! As soon I receive the answer I will req. to delete it, because I know it doesn't shows any code or whatever.

Link http://www.klix.ba/sport/nogomet/navijaci-galatasaraya-unistavali-stolice-na-emiratesu/141003042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.manifestic.com/images/smpanda.jpg">
```

JQuery

```
var resized;
$('#myImage').click(function(){
    if (!resized) {
        $(this).animate({'width':632,'height':470}, 300);
        resized = true;    
    }
    else if (resized) {
        $(this).animate({'width':283,'height':360}, 300);
        resized = false;    
    }

    return false;
});
```

Look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vg2cpa3h/)

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the source code of that page:

```
$('a.resizeimg').click(function(){
                if (!resized) {
                    $(this).find("figure").hide();
                    $(this).parent().animate({'width':632,'height':470}, 300);
                    $(this).find("img").animate({'width':632,'height':470}, 300, function(){
                        $('a.resizeimg').find("figure").show();
                        var header = parseInt($("header").css("height"));
                        if(header == 92) {
                            clanakHeight = parseInt($('article.clanak').height())+69-parseInt($(".additional").height());
                        }
                        else if(header == 51) {
                            clanakHeight = parseInt($('article.clanak').height())+181-parseInt($(".additional").height());
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).next("p.opis").animate({'width':622}, 300);
                    $(this).find("figure").css({'width':632,'height':470});
                    resized = true;
                }
                else if (resized) {
                    $(this).find("figure").hide();
                    $(this).parent().animate({'width':316,'height':235}, 300);
                    $(this).find("img").animate({'width':316,'height':235}, 300,function(){
                        $('a.resizeimg').find("figure").show();
                        var header = parseInt($("header").css("height"));
                        if(header == 92) {
                            clanakHeight = parseInt($('article.clanak').height())+69-parseInt($(".additional").height());
                        }
                        else if(header == 51) {
                            clanakHeight = parseInt($('article.clanak').height())+181-parseInt($(".additional").height());
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).find("figure").css({'width':316,'height':235});
                    $(this).next("p.opis").animate({'width':306}, 300);
                    resized = false;    
                }

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Hi Joakim, do you know maybe how I can simplify it?

Comment: Check my new answer below!